# Jquery scroll to section based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to make these images which when you click on them they scroll to the id given in the `data-down` attribute. However when I try it it does not scoll. When you do a console log of the variable that contains the id to scroll to it is correct so I don't know why it isn't working.

```
<header>
    <div id="header-content">
        <h1>Welcome to the JETS Lake Garda Campaign</h1>
        <img class="down" data-down="#about" src="images/down.png">
    </div>
</header>
<section id="about">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Libero minus dicta, sapiente, dolor, quidem quisquam magnam expedita eos voluptates saepe itaque maiores facilis sit nihil consequuntur vero hic possimus inventore autem. Voluptate amet dicta corporis dolorum facilis, quisquam.</p>
    <img class="down" data-down="#sailors" src="images/down.png">
</section>
<section id="sailors">
    <h2>Sailors</h2>
    <p>Libero minus dicta, sapiente, dolor, quidem quisquam magnam expedita eos voluptates saepe itaque maiores facilis sit nihil consequuntur vero hic possimus inventore autem. Voluptate amet dicta corporis dolorum facilis, quisquam.</p>
    <div class="down" data-down="#sponsors" src="images/down.png">
</section>
<section id="sponsors">
    <h2>Sponsors</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque, pariatur. Aliquam ab in, ullam nostrum quis eos, commodi at? Eos quod amet dignissimos dolorum consequuntur adipisci dolore ducimus quis.</p>
</section>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.down').on('click', function () {
        var toGo = $(this).data('down');
        console.log(toGo);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(toGo).offset.top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bc15bdu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `$(toGo).offset.top` with `$(toGo).offset().top`

Answer (score 0):

offset is a function, and therefore you should access it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Navigation buttons

  $('.down').on('click', function(){
    var toGo = $(this).data('down');
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(toGo).offset().top
    }, 'slow');

  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8bc15bdu/1/) is an updated working example.

Answer (score 0):

Uhoh Replace `$(toGo).offset.top` with `$(toGo).offset().top`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "scrollTo" jQuery extension. I used it on several projects and it's very easy to implement and debug :)

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo